# Agregar opción vacía a Combobox

Tags: combobox, symfony

Buen dia.

Estoy creando un combobox con symfony asi:

```
<section>
    {{ form_label(formulario.departamento, 'DEPART.', {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-1 col-lg-1'}}) }}
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-5">
        {{ form_widget(formulario.departamento, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        <span class="text-danger">{{ form_errors(formulario.departamento) }}</span><i></i>
    </div>
</section>
```

El detalle es que deseo agregar una primera opción "**SELECCIONE DEPARTAMENTO...**"

Ya intente con muchas formas incluso con ***'empty_value': 'Please select...'*** pero no funciona, alguna idea ??

Muy amables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se debe hacer en el Type

```
->add('departamento', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Departamento',
            'placeholder' => 'SELECCIONE DEPARTAMENO...',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC');
            }
        ))
```

Comment: +2 El auto aprendizaje, es una de las mejores formas de transmitir conocimientos.

Comment: Gracias @HéctorM.